# How to get text content of the entire document excluding HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to get all of the text from the current page. I am using `$('body').text()` but it doesn't seem to work as I would like it to work. When I do that, it returns some javascript too. I only want the visible text to be searched. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: document.getElementByTagName("body").textContent might be what you want?

Comment: @Snowmonkey That should just be `document.body.textContent`. It appears to be identical to `$('body').text()`, though.

Comment: Basically, you need to exclude `<script>`, `<style>` and `<noscript>`.

Comment: `$('body *:not(script,style,noscript)').text()`. It could be painfully slow though.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan this does not seem to work. If you run it in the chrome console, it returns some javascript. Try it on a website like google.

Comment: If you try it on the code in my answer, it works fine. Google's homepage doesn't include jQuery, so it won't work there.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan even after I inject jQuery into googles homepage, it includes some code

Answer (score 1):

The following will get you what you want. However, there are caveats.

```js
console.log(jQuery('body *:not(script,style,noscript)').text());
```

```html
<p>Needs me some text</p>
<style>
noscript { font-weight: bold; }
</style>
<noscript>
<div>whatever dude, I don't script anyway</div>
</noscript>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

See that `*`? That means every element that is a descendant of `body`. So the `:not()` is applied to to every element on the page, checking if it's `script`, `style` or `noscript`. If you're lucky, your browser supports this natively, so it does this with some relatively fast code, because depending on the size of your page and the number of elements within it, it could take a considerable amount of time to make that check.